# Memory leak with "new" operator and "&"? C++

Tags: c++, pointers, memory-leaks, reference, dynamic-memory-allocation

This will lead to memory leak:

```
int var = *new int(5);
```

This will not (if later freed):

```
int* var = new int(5);
```

**Question:** Will this lead to memory leak?

```
int& var = *new int(5);
```

Yes, I should use smart pointers instead but that is not the question :)

Comment: "should use smart pointers" ? really? I think you should just use `int var = 5;`

Comment: If you create something with "new" and don't destroy it with "delete", you have a leak.

Comment: Yes (@largest_prime_is_463035818), that is true. However this is just an exempel (not a practical one) and is more to understand how the language works (if it will lead to memory leak or not) so that I know how to use pointers when they are the only alternative, if that is ever going to happen to me.

Comment: _Will this lead to memory leak?_ Not necessarily; you need to take into account the [_as-if rule_](https://stackoverflow.com/q/15718262/580083). Live demo: https://godbolt.org/z/xxGf43.

Comment: @DanielLangr that's correct. Heap-allocation elision is a relatively new thing with compilers tho. See https://godbolt.org/z/bn7rTj

Comment: @AyxanHaqverdili Depends on a compiler. Clang elides these allocations since version 4 (on Godbolt).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It will cause a memory leak. What your doing there is allocating a block of memory, dereferencing the pointer and assigning it to the variable `var`. Dynamic memory allocation does not deallocate itself when gone out of the scope, instead the variable `var` will be destroyed, not the pointer that you allocated.

To delete it, what you need to do is something like this,

```cpp
int& var = *new int(5);
delete &var;
```

Comment: So it wont cause a memory leak as in the the first example, as long as I delete it?

Comment: @ViktorSkarve Yes, whenever you allocate memory dynamically, you need to manage its lifetime.

Answer (score 0):

Yes it will. I tested it in Visual studio and it does. Wherever you use `new` and don't have `delete`, you have a memory leak. You allocate a dynamic memory but never free it.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Yes it will leak.
As already comment there have to be a delete to every new.
There should be a warning on the assignment to the reference `&var`
of a then anonym heap variable `int(5)` for which is no proper handle available anymore.
Deleting as proposed in the other answer a reference is against the idea of a reference. The most important difference between reference and pointers is the benefit to expect that the reference always has a target, while one has to expect that a pointer is dangling or zero and to act like so. Additionally there is the paradigm, that one does not own a reference once it is passed over, so delete is the very last one should do with it.